# Twig loop and building hash

Tags: symfony, hash, twig

i have a problem with twig syntax and merge function ... I have multiple object with 2 field category and price.

I need to create an array or hash (i guess hash is easier but ... i try both) with sum of prices for each category.

So i try many code, and my last is :

```
{% set test = [ {'category': 'description', 'price':  '1'}, { 'category': 'abc', 'price': '2'}, { 'category':'description', 'price': '3'} ] %}

{% set listCategory={} %}

{% for line in test %}

    {% set new_category = { 'category': line.category, 'price': line.price } %}

    {% if loop.first %}
        {% set listCategory = listCategory|merge([new_category]) %}
    {% else %}
        {% set flag = false %}

        {% for category in listCategory %}
            {% if line['category'] == new_category['category'] %}

                {% set tmp = line['price'] + new_category['price'] %}
                {# i try it too#}
                {% set category = category|merge([tmp]) %}

                {# or i try this#}
                {% set category = category|merge({ (category.price) : category.price + new_category.price }) %}

                {{ dump(listCategory) }}

            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

I try it since 3 hours and i don't know where i make an error.
When i check my array, i test if the key 'name' exist

if yes, i want to add the price of element to the hash price

if no, i want to add a new array in hash with key = 'name'

Anyone have an idea ? thx for your reading.

Comment: Personally, I would just make a twig extension for this sort of coding.  End up with lineCategory = test | generateLineCategory .  Life is too short to spend it trying to make template language work as a general purpose language.

Comment: you should have right, but i never make my own twig extension, so i try tu use my knowlegde to find a working solution, that's all. I

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for something similar to:

```
{% set test = [ {'category': 'description', 'price':  1}, { 'category': 'abc', 'price': 2}, { 'category':'description', 'price': 3} ] %}

{% set listCategory={} %}

{% for line in test %}

    {% set key = line.category %}

    {% if listCategory[key] is defined %}

        {# notice here that the key is in brackets () because otherwise it will be interpreted as the string "key" %}
        {% set listCategory = listCategory|merge({(key):listCategory[line.category]+line.price}) %}

    {% else %}

        {% set listCategory = listCategory|merge({(key):line.price}) %}

    {% endif %}

    {{ key }}: {{ listCategory[key] }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thx for your tips, its working =) just a little detail for averyone, i add a test in  the 'if' function
`{% if listCategory[key] is defined %}`

Comment: @Quovandius you are welcome, I have updated the answer to reflect